# Replace with ranges and hash maps

Tags: javascript, regex, range

In the snippet below I am trying to replace hashmaps found from ranges.

```js
var maps = new Array();

maps["k"] = 'Letter K';
maps["g"] = 'Letter G';
maps["c"] = 'Letter C';

var regex = /([kgc])a([kgc])a([kgc])a/g;

var text = 'kagaca';

text = text.replace(regex,maps["$1"]+maps["$2"]+maps["$3"]);//this does'nt work

console.log(text);

text = 'kagaca';
text = text.replace(regex,maps["k"]+' '+ maps["g"]+' '+ maps["c"]);//this works

console.log(text);
```

Statically regular expression works,I am stuck at replacing it from ranges.

Comment: `text = text.replace(regex, ($0, $1, $2, $3) => maps[$1]+maps[$2]+maps[$3])`

Comment: `"$1"` is string _$1_, not the value in the first captured group which is `undefined` & `undefined + undefined` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succed using a declarated function in `replace`. I think javascript misunderstand the `$X`called in map.

```js
var maps = new Array();

maps["k"] = 'Letter K';
maps["g"] = 'Letter G';
maps["c"] = 'Letter C';

var regex = /([kgc])a([kgc])a([kgc])a/g;

var text = 'kagaca';

text = text.replace(regex,function(){
  return maps[arguments[1]]+maps[arguments[2]]+maps[arguments[3]]
});//this now works

console.log(text);

text = 'kagaca';
text = text.replace(regex,maps["k"]+' '+ maps["g"]+' '+ maps["c"]);//this works

console.log(text);
```